# Applying a set of ordinary differential equations to each grid cell

Tags: r, ode, differential-equations

I am developing an agent-based model to simulate the spread of infectious diseases in heterogeneous landscapes composed of habitat polygons (or clumps of connected cells). To simplify the model, I consider a habitat grid (or raster) containing the polygon ID of each cell. In addition, I have epidemiological parameters associated with each polygon ID. At each time step, the parameter values change in the polygon. Thus, the data frame `landscape` (see below) is updated at each time step. Here is an example at t = 0:

```
landscape <- data.frame(polygon_ID = seq(1, 10, by = 1), 
                        beta = sample(c(100, 200, 400, 600), 10, replace = TRUE), 
                        gamma = sample(c(25, 26, 27, 28), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

To study the disease dynamics, I also am developing a compartmental model based on a system of ordinary differential equations (ODEs). Here is an example to represent the system of ODEs:

```
solve_sir_model <- function (times, parameters) { 

  sir_model <- function (times, states, parameters) { 

    with(as.list(c(states, parameters)), { 

      dSdt <- -beta*S*I 
      dIdt <- beta*S*I-gamma*I 
      dRdt <- gamma*I 
      dNdt <- dSdt + dIdt + dRdt 

      return(list(c(dSdt, dIdt, dRdt, dNdt))) 

    }) 
  } 

  states <- c(S = 99, I = 1, R = 0, N = 100) 
  return(ode(y = states, times = times, func = sir_model, parms = parameters)) 
} 

require(deSolve) 
output <- as.data.frame(solve_sir_model(times = seq(0, 5, by = 1), parameters = c(beta = 400, gamma = 28)))
```

At each time step, is it possible to apply the system of ODEs to each habitat polygon (thus each row) in the data frame `landscape`? I am using lsoda as an ODE solver. Do I need to use another solver to apply the ODEs at each time step?

**EDIT**

It seems that the method `iteration` in the function `ode` can be useful in my case:

> Method "iteration" is special in that here the function func should
>   return the new value of the state variables rather than the rate of
>   change. This can be used for individual based models, for difference
>   equations, or in those cases where the integration is performed within
>   func).

I have tested the method but I don't understand why it doesn't work with a single time step:

```
solve_sir_model <- function (times, parameters) { 

  sir_model <- function (times, states, parameters) { 

    with(as.list(c(states, parameters)), { 

      dSdt <- -beta*S*I 
      dIdt <- beta*S*I-gamma*I 
      dRdt <- gamma*I 
      dNdt <- dSdt + dIdt + dRdt 

      return(list(c(dSdt, dIdt, dRdt, dNdt))) 

    }) 
  } 

  states <- c(S = 99, I = 1, R = 0, N = 100) 
  return(ode(y = states, times = times, func = sir_model, parms = parameters, method = "iteration")) 
} 

require(deSolve) 
output <- as.data.frame(solve_sir_model(times = 1, parameters = c(beta = 400, gamma = 28)))

 Error in iteration(y, times, func, parms, ...) : 
   times should be equally spaced In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: You should check out the [ReacTran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ReacTran/index.html) package for models with a spatial component like this, as they have helper functions to set up your grid, etc. It sounds like you're talking about temporally variable parameters, which can also be accommodated by `ReacTran`, but beware that sharp (i.e. discrete) shifts in parameters cause problems with numerical solvers. I'd recommend approximating the parameters over time using something like `approxfun`.

Comment: (That's assuming that the polygons interact. Do they?)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't know this package but it seems that it is used for partial differential equations. There are no diffusion and advection terms in my equations. In my agent-based model, the habitat polygons don't interact. Only host individuals (i.e., susceptible, infected and recovered individuals) can interact with their environment.

Comment: In that case, `ReacTran` is overkill. Yes, you can have multiple non-interacting polygons by simply having arrays of length `n` (where `n` is the number of polygons) for each of `S`, `I`, and `R` and `N` that are combined into one array. (Personally, I'd calculate `N` at the end to save time.) Pass the function your state variable array, which would be `4 * n` long. Then, inside your model split it into four parts. So, for example, `S <- states[1:n]`, `I <- states[(n+1):(2*n)]`. The rest stays pretty much the same, except you'd need to have an initial state array that is `4 * n` in length.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But how can I apply the model to each polygon at a given time step? When I run my model, I obtain results for `S`, `I`, and `R` over all time period (in my case, `times = seq(0, 5, by = 1)`).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
# Library *not* require
library(deSolve)

# Parameters: number of polygons, beta, & gamma
n.polys <- 10 
beta <- sample(c(100, 200, 400, 600), n.polys, replace = TRUE)
gamma <- sample(c(25, 26, 27, 28), n.polys, replace = TRUE)

# Model defintion
sir_model <- function (t, Y, pars) { 
  # Break up state variable into parts
  S <- Y[1:n.polys]
  I <- Y[(n.polys+1):(2 * n.polys)]
  R <- Y[(2 * n.polys+1):(3 * n.polys)]

  # Calculate rate of change
  dSdt <- -beta * S * I 
  dIdt <- beta * S * I - gamma * I 
  dRdt <- gamma * I 

  # Return rates of change after concatenating them 
  return(list(c(dSdt, dIdt, dRdt))) 
} 

# Initial conditions
Y.ini <- c(S = rep(99, n.polys), I = rep(1, n.polys), R = rep(0, n.polys)) 

# Solve the model
ode(y = Y.ini, times = 0:5, func = sir_model, parms = NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In this case, you run the model over the entire time period (i.e., times = 0:5). Suppose two individual populations 1 and 2. The population 1 is controlled by the agent-based model (ABM) and the population 2 by the ODEs. In addition, the density of individuals of type 2 depends on the density of individuals of type 1. In my case, I need run my ODEs at a given time step because the density of individuals of type 1 (S1, I1 and R1) within the habitat polygons change at each time step and this change is controlled by the agent-based model.

Comment: For example for a given habitat polygon, S1 = 5 individuals at t = 0. At t = 1, individuals of type 1 move in the landscape (controlled by the ABM), thus S1 changes and is equal to 10. Next, I apply my ODEs to calculate the density of individuals of type 2 (S2, I2 and R2) from S1 within the habitat polygon. So, I wonder if it is possible to apply the ODEs at a given time step (thus at each time step controlled by the ABM).

Comment: First of all, when you say *time step* I think you are actually referring to output times. Time steps are (often) selected by the ODE solver and you know nothing about them, as you're just given a solution at the times you request. It's important to remember this. What you describe sounds convoluted, but possible. I'd look at the help file for `events` in the `deSolve` package. This should let you link you ODE model to your ABM.